# Getting Internal Details of Media Player in Android

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I want to analyze and debug how a `video` file is played in android. I searched a lot but I only got how `MediaPlayer` class interacts with internal **media-player** engine and I am unable to get how internal **media-player** engine works in android. Any help is appreciated. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MediaPlayer` (`MediaPlayer.java`) is the main `MediaPlayer` abstraction from an application perspective. It interacts with it's native `MediaPlayer` implementation (`Mediaplayer.cpp`) through a `JNI` interface (`android_media_Mediaplayer.cpp`).

The type of `player` to be created is decided through the parameters in `MediaPlayerService` through [`MediaPlayerFactory`](http://androidxref.com/4.2.2_r1/xref/frameworks/av/media/libmediaplayerservice/MediaPlayerFactory.cpp#108). Typically `StagefrightPlayer` or `NuPlayer` are created.

If `StagefrightPlayer` is created, then the actual `player` implemented by `AwesomePlayer`.

`AwesomePlayer` exposes *similar* `API` to the main `MediaPlayer` implementation and hence, you can find an almost **1:1** mapping between the two, except for `MediaPlayer::start` which is implemented by `AwesomePlayer::play`.

`AwesomePlayer` will create `MediaExtractor` which internally will create the abstractions for specific tracks as `MediaTrack` which act as the source for the individual `tracks`.

`AwesomePlayer` internally creates the `audio` and `video` track specific objects such as `AudioPlayer` and `OMXCodec`.

I have answered another question of yours here: [What is meant by event in Android Media Player?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15664963/what-is-meant-by-event-in-android-media-player/15672816#15672816) which outlines the `AV Synchronization` and functionality of `AwesomePlayer` in handling the `video` track.

I hope this information is sufficient for your study.