# What is meant by event in Android Media Player?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am trying to analyze flow of messages exchanged while playing a video in Android. I came across this image while doing so.

http://img521.imageshack.us/img521/3585/capturehb.png

Then I went through the source files for AwesomePlayer and TimedEventQueue. I am unable to get what is meant by event in those files.
Any help regarding this is appreciated. 
Thank you.

Link for TimedEventQueue source files is attached below.

https://github.com/cozybit/aosp-frameworks-base/blob/master/media/libstagefright/TimedEventQueue.cpp

Answer (score 2):

In general, `TimedEventQueue` is a mechanism by which an `event` is pushed into a `queue` with a specific `timeout`. At the end of the `timeout`, a function associated with the `event` is **invoked** which will perform some functionality. Coming to the relation of `AwesomePlayer` and `TimedEventQueue`, please find an overview of this relationship as below.

In Android, `AwesomePlayer` is the core implementation of the player engine which spawns of the `video` and `audio` track related paths and helps in the overall functioning of the `player` engine.

In addition to this, `AwesomePlayer` serves as a **SINK** for the `video` track i.e. a bridge between `OMXCodec` i.e. `video decoder` implementation and display pipeline i.e. `SurfaceTexture`. Before going into the `TimedEventQueue`, a brief summary of operation is as below.

The `player` engine works in a `pull` model and `AwesomePlayer` pulls the video frame from the decoder through the `read` call. Once a *video frame* is available, `AV Synchronization` logic comes into picture which will decide when to `render` the frame. Once the frame is ready to be rendered, it is passed to the `SurfaceTexture` module through the `mVideoRenderer->render` call.

Coming to `TimedEventQueue`, `AwesomePlayer` uses this concept to achieve the aforementioned functionality. When a `start` is called, a `postVideoEvent_l()` is invoked. By default, there is a time delay implemented in the android tree after which this event is triggered. When this event is triggered, a corresponding function is invoked. In this case, `onVideoEvent` is invoked which will then proceed with the blocking `read` call.

After a video buffer is received, if the *video frame* is earlier than the *audio track timestamp* by 10 ms, then another `postVideoEvent_l(10000)` is triggered which will force this thread to sleep for 10 ms more, after which `onVideoEvent` is again triggered.

Similarly, after a video frame is `rendered`, then `AwesomePlayer` will trigger another `postVideoEvent_l()` which will sleep for **default** period of time and come back and block in `read` call again.

Comment: Thank you so much... It would be very helpful if you suggest any reference for this topic... Thank you...

Comment: @KiranKumarManku By reference, if you are looking for a book, personally I am not aware if there is a book that explains at this level. The next best thing is to either read the code and draw up one's own understanding or get the same information from someone who is fingers' deep into the code. This is what I have tried to capture in my comment which is based on my work on this code.